# differential angle while deriving surface area of a sphere

Tags: integration

while trying to derive the surface area of a sphere, I came across this in a video..https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=184s&v=J42wNwCh0Mk
I didn't understand why ds= r*d(theta).. how does a small element of angle multiplied by the radius gives ds?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at it is if you have a radius of length $r$, and you rotate the radius by an angle $\theta$, it traces out a piece of a circle with arc length $r\theta$ (for example, if you trace out a complete revolution $\theta=2\pi$, the arc length is the circumference of a circle $2\pi r$).

This means that on circular curves, we have $s = r\theta$ and $\frac{ds}{d\theta} = r$, and so over short circle-like regions of any curve, we have that $ds=r\,d\theta$

Comment: oh I feel stupid now..... it makes complete sense when theta is in radians.

Comment: thanks! this was helpful

Comment: No worries! It's actually a good justification for using radians, and it always helps to be able to see things in more than one way.